# How change resolution screen of virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

04 and I install Mountain lion via virtual box, and I want to known how I can get full resolution with my monitor. I try to install Guesst adittions and it tells me that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Well it is as they say:

> VirtualBox does not provide Guest Additions for Mac OS X at this time. <sup>[Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch14.html)</sup>

So any features of guest additions will not be available in the experimental support of Mac OS X by Virtual Box.